# Magento conditional <customer_logged_out> strange behavior

Tags: xml, magento, configuration-files

What I want to do is to add a little js file if the user is ***not*** logged in.
I have this scenario:
file catalog.xml:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
 <default>
  ....
 </default>
  <catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Product View (Any)</label>
    <reference name="head">
      <action method="addJs">
        <script>varien/configurable.js</script>
      </action>
    </reference>
    ....
  </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

I wrote a local.xml file like this:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <customer_logged_out>
    <catalog_product_view translate="label">
      <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs">
          <script>varien/file.js</script>
        </action>
      </reference>    
    </catalog_product_view>
  </customer_logged_out>
</layout>
```

This does not work and the file is not added.
But, if I get rid of the catalog_product_view tag, it does:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <customer_logged_out>
    <!--<catalog_product_view translate="label">-->
      <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs">
          <script>varien/file.js</script>
        </action>
      </reference>    
    <!--</catalog_product_view>-->
  </customer_logged_out>
</layout>
```

I suppose, I did not tested, that in this way the file is added in all the pages, though I would like to add it only in the catalog_product_view.

Probably I don't understand all the logic of the config xml files.
Can anybody kindly explain me this particular case?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`customer_logged_out` handle is loaded for all pages when the customer is not logged in. and you cannot use 2 layout handles one under an other.
But you can achieve what you need via an observer.
In one of your modules add this in the `config.xml` file inside the `config` tag

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>
            <observers>
                <[module]>
                    <class>[Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>addJs</method>
                </[module]>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

then create the file `[Namespace]/[Module]/Model/Observer.php` with this content

```
<?php
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer
{
    public function addJs($observer)
    {
        /** @var Mage_Customer_Model_Session $customerSession */
        $customerSession = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
        $action = $observer->getEvent()->getAction()->getFullActionName();
        if (!$customerSession->isLoggedIn() && $action == 'catalog_product_view') {
            $head = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
            if ($head) {
                $head->addJs('varien/file.js');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

clear the cache and you are done.